# CoreML for AudioKit DSP

Tags: signal-processing, audiokit, coreml

I've been trying to determine if it is possible to integrate CoreML models for the purpose of creating custom AudioKit Effect Nodes. I'm curious if anyone has tried this previously and if they might have some resources to ensure I'm approaching this problem correctly.

Presently, I've created a custom AudioKit node that loads my model(s) and buffers frames until enough frames are available to perform a prediction. Once the input has enough data, its loaded into a MLMultiarray and passed to the model to perform a prediction... but the prediction call I believe is blocking the audio thread, so this is definitely not the correct way to do this... I think.

I'm not sure if utilizing GCD is appropriate but I'm trying presently testing this...

Hoping someone might have some insights or resources that might assist how this might be achieved, certainly could be awesome utilize the neural engine for DSP :) Everything I've seen so far is just about classification, not DSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the Neural Engine is indeed that you have no control over how long it will block the audio thread. I do my ML in the audio thread using the CPU (not using Core ML).

Comment: When you say you do your ML in the audio thread using the CPU, not coreml... I take it your not just setting the model configuration compute unites to cpu only... could you elaborate on how your handling ML in the audio thread? Love your book btw... has been very useful!

Comment: I write my own neural networking code because that's the only way to know that you're not blocking anything. Maybe Core ML in cpuOnly mode will work fine, or you can use the BNNS framework directly. But there's no guarantee these things won't allocate anything behind your back, or block in some other way.

Comment: Matthijs, thank you very much for elaborating on this. It sounds like we might need to tackle our implementation of this network, but first I'm going to try and check out BNNS and see if we can get somewhere with that framework.